# spring entity concurrency control while persisting into database

Tags: spring, entity-framework, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to control concurrent access to same object in spring+jpa configuration.
For Example, I have an entity named A. Now multiple processes updating the same object of A.
I am using versioning field but controlling it but here is the issue:
For example 2 processes reads the same entity (A) having version=1.
Now one process update the entity and version gets incremented.
when 2nd process tries to persist the object, Optimistic lock exception would be thrown.
I am using spring services and repository to access the objects.
Could you please help me here?

Comment: What is your desired outcome of the scenario that you described? What would you like to happen?

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19456821/1356423

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem then? That's how it's supposed to work.

You can catch the JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException and then decide what to do from there.

This, for example, would give a validation error message on a Spring MVC form:

```
...
if(!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
  try {
    fooRepository.save(foo);
  } catch (JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException exp){
      bindingResult.reject("", "This record was modified by another user. Try refreshing the page.");
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I was expecting if hibernate or jpa itself can handle this exception and reload the object.

Comment: @richyrich Reloading isn't always the best choice, so they leave that up to you.